# For loop in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Total noob in Mysql alert.

need to run simple For loop to insert data into table. Copying For [loop example from docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/loop.html):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 10 THEN
      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
  SET @x = p1;
END;
```

Shows bunch of errors in Workbench editor window:

[image]

Eg, first error for "p1" tells:

> "p1" is not valid for this position, expecting an identifier

Checked MySQL version - `SELECT @@version;`, its 5.7, the same as from docs page. Workbench version is 8.0

Not sure what other info I can provide.

Comment: What happens if you try to create and then run the stored proc?

Comment: Have you set delimiters (procedure syntaxes for me if I do) and runs fine..

Comment: Thanks, wasnt able to answer quicker. Answer solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **MySQL Workbench**

when creating a stored routine on `Query Tab` you need to explicitly set `delimiter` before `create procedure..`

[image]

```
DELIMITER $$ -- this symbol can be anything other than default ;
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
  label1: LOOP
    SET p1 = p1 + 1;
    IF p1 < 10 THEN
      ITERATE label1;
    END IF;
    LEAVE label1;
  END LOOP label1;
  SET @x = p1;
END $$
DELIMITER ; -- once completed we are resting back to default
```

When creating a routine under `Routine Tab` you need not to include delimiter

[image]

Since when clicking Apply it will automatically builds it.

[image]